# Не запускается iframe приложение вконтакте

Tags: iframe, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Не запускается iframe приложение, в качестве сервера на время разработки использую локальный open server. Сделал всё, как в документации, подключил скрипт `//vk.com/js/api/xd_connection.js?2`, сделал инициализацию `VK.init`, но при запуске ничего не происходит. В консоли хрома во время загрузки приложения появляется ошибка при отправке get запроса по адресу index.php на моём сервере. Уже всё перепробовал, ничего не помогает.

Скриншот запуска приложения:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> использую локальный open server

1) Одно из предположений не совпадает hash. Интересно было бы знать, какие настройки адреса вставляете и какой адрес перебивает open server.

2) У вас нет проблем с http и https? На странице https в iframe может быть размещен только сайт https.